# Why does the program get stuck when opening a successfully created name pipe?

Tags: c, named-pipes

I'm new to pipe and socket programming and took a shot at creating a simple program that uses named pipes.

The code (that is relevant to the matter in question) is below:

```
getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

char * pipename = malloc(PIPENAME_SIZE * sizeof(char)); 
strcat(pipename, cwd);
strcat(pipename, ".pipe");
unlink(pipename);

if (mkfifo(pipename, 0644) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating FIFO.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

printf("I'm here\n");
fflush(stdin);

int fd_receive = open(pipename, O_RDONLY);

printf("And now I'm here\n");
fflush(stdin);
```

When I execute the program, the output is

```
I'm here
```

Why does it get stuck when opening the file? Is it a matter of permissions? I have looked around and could not find anyone with the same problem, so I'm guessing it's a detail that a noobie like me would have missed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's blocking until something else opens the write end of the pipe. See [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo)

Comment: Also, `fflush(stdin);` is undefined. Did you mean to flush `stdout`?

Comment: You have answered my question, thank you.
Would it be possible for this program to open a pipe (and not being blocked by performing that action) and allowing for another "client" program to open the write end of the pipe to then communicate with this process?

Comment: Yes, I did mean to flush `stdout`. :)

Comment: You can open the fifo in non-blocking mode and then use `poll()` or `select()` or the like to tell when it can be read from without an error.

Comment: Yet again, thank you. Feel free to post an answer so I can mark this as answered. :)